# Create inline std::string

Tags: c++

Is it possible to initialize a `std::string` without creating a variable?

What I wish to accomplish:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + strerror(errno));
```

What I do currently:

```
std::string error = "Error: ";
std::string errmsg(strerror(errno));
throw std::runtime_error(error + errmsg);
```

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error( std::string("Error: ") + strerror(errno) );`

Comment: @M.M: Or with [C++14 built-in user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s): `throw std::runtime_error("Error: "s + strerror(errno));`

Comment: If you're doing this often in your code then defining your own exception type might be a good idea, and do this work in the ctor-initializer list. Then you can write `throw my_error(errno);` or even `throw my_error();`

Comment: @M.M: You need a `using namespace` for it (I linked docs in my first comment so they'd know), but no extra includes to my knowledge. Not going to swear there aren't evil weirdo compilers out there that violate the spec though.

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, that's a suggestion. Not to mention you have taught me about unnamed objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just make a temporary out of one of them:

```
throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Error: ") + strerror(errno));
```

The [`operator+` overload for `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) can take `const char*` as well as `std::string`.

If you have access to C++14, you can `using namespace std::literals` and do it this way:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error: "s + strerror(errno));
```